# How to add blank space in proof environment without changing the position of the word "proof"?

Tags: spacing, theorems

I LaTeX my homework, and for one problem, I want only white space in the proof environment since I'll be hand-drawing a picture. when I type in

```
\begin{proof}
\vspace{1in}
\end{proof}
```

the outcome is

[image]

i.e., the word "proof" goes to the bottom. Is there any way to move the word back to the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set something - a zero-width, empty box like `\mbox{}` - so that the `proof` title is set, and then issue your `1in` `v`ertical `space`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
A regular theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
\mbox{}\par
\vspace{1in}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The reason for the way it currently is displayed is because the `proof` environment is actually a *list*... actually a single-item list. These items are only set once you set the list entry. So, using `\mbox{}` acts like setting something and therefore prints the visible `Proof.`.

Comment: Possibly `\vspace*` and `\nopagebreak` after `\par`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a minipage, so there will not be any possible page break points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for adding context

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\pictureproof}[1]{%
  % #1 = space to reserve
  \par\noindent
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
  \begin{proof}\strut\vspace{#1}\par
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \mbox{}
  \end{proof}
  \end{minipage}
  \par\addvspace{6pt plus 6pt}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{theorem}
Something meaningful to fill the statement of a theorem
possibly taking two lines of text.
\end{theorem}

\pictureproof{1in}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{proof}
This is done just for showing the space after a proof.
\end{proof}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]