# Bug in proof environment?

Tags: amsthm

I am trying to give students an empty space for a proof.  So it should start the with the word `Proof` then empty space,  then the little square at the bottom of the empty space.  When I specify the empty space (1cm in the example below), the `Proof` and qed symbol is put on the same line and I get the empty space before or after this line.  Why does `proof` do this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
Regular proof environment with space
\begin{proof}
  \vspace{1cm}
\end{proof}
The same but starting with tilde
\begin{proof}
  ~\vspace{1cm}
\end{proof}
Some text after the proof  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\vspace`, when entered in horizontal mode, is deferred until the end of the paragraph.  One way to get around this is to put something invisible in the proof: `\begin{proof} $ $\par` and then the `\vspace`.  (I'm putting this in a comment since I am unable to test, and I don't like to post untested answers.)

Comment: The suggestion of @barbarabeeton works, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @barbara mentioned, I also think the proof environment is actually a list and you need to set the list entry (have a look in [How to add blank space in proof environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360303/how-to-add-blank-space-in-proof-environment-without-changing-the-position-of-the))

So you can use a "placeholder" or a empty box and after that paragraph call the `vspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

Prove that...
    \begin{proof}
        \mbox{}\par
        \vspace{3cm}
    \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, though Barbara's answer is a bit less typing.