# How to add blank space in the proof environment with qed symbol at the bottom of the page?

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing, proof-package

**How to add blank space in the proof environment with qed symbol at the bottom of the page?**  I don't want only have a few lines of blank space.  I want the space to be filled until the last line of the given page.  I want to create a handout where students can write a proof on the whole page.

I looked at the solution offered by [How to add blank space in proof environment without changing the position of the word "proof"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360303/how-to-add-blank-space-in-proof-environment-without-changing-the-position-of-the), but it doesn't fill the proof environment with vertical space until the end of the page.
This solution only gave me something like

> **Proof**
>
> [some space]
>
> [some space]
>
> [some space]
>
> [some space and then the qed symbol]

However, the vspace command does not fill the proof environment until the end of the page.

I tried using

```
\begin{proof}
\vfill
\end{proof}
```

But it produced something like this.

> **Proof**  [some space until the end of the line followed by the QED symbol in this same line]

Thank you for helping me.

---

OK, this is what I had.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\vfill
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
\mbox{}\par
\vspace{1in}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

It gave me the result below.

[image]

The bottom qed sign is not at the bottom line of the page.

Comment: Please always provide full but minimal examples such that we know eaxtly what you are doing, which class and packages you are using and such that we have an example we can copy and test as is.

Comment: @daleif OK, done

Comment: May I ask why do you want it to be moved to the bottom of the page? That seems wasteful to me

Comment: @daleif  I want to create a handout where students can write a proof on the whole page.

Comment: Right, you should add that to your question (then it does not sound so strange)

Comment: @daleif  OK, added.  Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: This seems to work `\strut\par\vspace{\stretch{1}}`, note that `\par` is needed (`\strut` is similar to your `\mbox{}`)

Comment: @daleif  That is perfect.  Could you please make that an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note in general many of the space inserting macros need *something to push against*.

So here

```
\begin{proof}
 \strut\vfill
\end{proof}
```

should work. As does

```
\begin{proof}
 \strut\par\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\end{proof}
```

But do remember to leave enough space on the page for the students handwriting.

Comment: I can't upvote your answer because I have not enough reputation, but thank you very much for your quick answer.